# Split file in columns, filter and print them

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have been given an assignment to do. Here are the instructions:

Write a Perl program to accomplish each of the following on the file solar.txt (see link at
the class homepage)

1. Print all records that do not list a discoverer in the eighth field.
2. Print every record after erasing the second field. Note: It would be better to say
   "print every record" omitting the second field.
3. Print the records for satellites that have negative orbital periods. (A negative
   orbital period simply means that the satellite orbits in a counterclockwise
   direction.)
4. Print the data for the objects discovered by the Voyager2 space probe.
5. Print each record with the orbital period given in seconds rather than days.

About solar.txt file:
This file contains lines of 9 items, the first being:
Adrastea XV Jupiter 129000 0.30 0.00 0.00 Jewitt 1979
in alphabetical order by the name of the planet or moon (first field).
The text in [] is the corresponding field from the line above.

The fields in this file are:

1. Name of planet or moon [Adrastea]
2. Number of moon or planet (roman numerals) [XV]
3. Name of the abject around which the satellite orbits [Jupiter]
4. Orbital radius (semimajor axis) in kilometers [129000]
5. Orbital period in days [0.30]
6. Orbital inclination in degrees [0.00]
7. Orbital eccentricity [0.00]
8. Discoverer [Jewitt]
9. Year of discovery [1979]

I am stuck on the first instruction. I can read in the "solar.txt" file, but after that I can't do it or can't figure it out. Splitting the array seems like the best option, but is not working for me at the moment. Here's the code:

```
#usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open (SOLAR_FILE, "C:/perl_tests/solar.txt") or die "Could not open the file!";
my @array = (<SOLAR_FILE>);
close (SOLAR_FILE);

for (my $i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    my @tempArray = split(/ /, $array[$i]);
    if ($tempArray[$i] eq "-") {
        print "@tempArray";
    }
}

open (SOLAR_FILE, "C:/perl_tests/solar.txt") or die "Could not open the file!";
my @array = (<SOLAR_FILE>);
close (SOLAR_FILE);

for my $record (@array) {
    my @tempArray = split(/ /, $record);
    if ($tempArray[2] eq qw(Jupiter, Uranus, Saturn, Pluto, Mars, Sun, Neptune, Earth)
    s//???/" "/g;
    #I know something goes where the (???) are, but I'm not sure how to do it.
    {
    print "@tempArray";
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure how to start the other 4. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be helpful.

EDIT: Here's the info from the file:

```
Adrastea XV Jupiter 129000 0.30 0.00 0.00 Jewitt 1979
Amalthea V Jupiter 181000 0.50 0.40 0.00 Barnard 1892
Ananke XII Jupiter 21200000 -631 147.00 0.17 Nicholson 1951
Ariel I Uranus 191000 2.52 0.00 0.00 Lassell 1851
Atlas XV Saturn 138000 0.60 0.00 0.00 Terrile 1980
Belinda XIV Uranus 75000 0.62 0.03 0.00 Voyager2 1986
Bianca VIII Uranus 59000 0.43 0.16 0.00 Voyager2 1986
...
Leda XIII Jupiter 11094000 238.72 27.00 0.15 Kowal 1974
Lysithea X Jupiter 11720000 259.22 29.00 0.11 Nicholson 1938
Mars IV Sun 227940000 686.98 1.85 0.09 - -
Megaclite XIX Jupiter 23911000 ? ? ? Sheppard 2000
Mercury I Sun 57910000 87.97 7.00 0.21 - -
Metis XVI Jupiter 128000 0.29 0.00 0.00 Synnott 1979
Mimas I Saturn 186000 0.94 1.53 0.02 Herschel 1789
Miranda V Uranus 130000 1.41 4.22 0.00 Kuiper 1948
Moon I Earth 384000 27.32 5.14 0.05 - -
Naiad III Neptune 48000 0.29 0.00 0.00 Voyager2 1989
Neptune VIII Sun 4504300000 60190.00 1.77 0.01 Adams 1846
...
```

Comment: What do the lines which do not list a discoverer look like? Are there other lines with information missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check 8th field for something other than `-`: `if ($fields[7] ne '-') { ... }`
2. Delete 2nd field: `splice(@fields, 1, 0);`
3. Check 5th field for negative: `if ($fields[4] < 0) { ... }`
4. Check 8th field for `Voyager2`: `if ($fields[7] eq 'Voyager2') { ... }`
5. Impossible. The number of seconds in a day is not the same for every day. However, the approximate result given by `$fields[4]*24*60*60` will probably be within tolerance.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I'll keep this open for extra input/comments just in case.

Comment: @user2203636: take care that after step 2 the Orbital period is in the 4th field and no more in the 5th one.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop is iterating over the fields; it should iterate over the entire array of lines:

```
for my $record (@array) {
    my $tempArray = split(/ /, $record);

    if ($tempArray[7] eq "-") # test 8th field
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

This assumes that you are splitting each line correctly; that is, that the delimiter between fields is a space character.

Comment: @user2203636 - Can you post a sample of the file contents?

Comment: @user2203636 - I took another look at your program and updated my answer.

Comment: I have added the content of the file. There are no lines skipped. that is for readability.